# IR tracking system in UAV , where to start

Tags: ros, uav

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, so I have a UAV supported with ErleBrain 2.0 and I want to detect and track the IR signal:

There will be an IR transmitters in the ground (transmits the signal everywhere) , and the UAV will have 4 IR receivers (one receiver in each side)

What I want to do is: I'll first analyse the signal of the 4 IR receivers ( in the UAV) and the based on the signal , say for example if the right receiver  received stronger signal so based on this, the UAV should turn right and check the reading again.

My question is where to start?? if I want to move the UAV based on the IR receivers readings autonomously ??
do you have an open source or package on ROS, is there are any documents that I can read. I just have a problem with the start point, once I have a clue then I can work :)

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241875/ir-tracking-system-in-uav-,-where-to-start/) by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, since your question is so specific. But if you're wondering how to start using the ROS framework, check out the tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) with karma: 61 on 2016-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on 2016-08-17**:
hello, I saw the tutorial but I didn't find what I want, I want to move the drone based on sensor readings : IR receiver, if the signal is coming from the right the UAV should turn right and search, if the signal is coming from the front the UAV should continue straight and so on

**Comment by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) on 2016-08-17**:
Do you need help figuring out how to command your UAV based on some measurements, i.e. a mathematical problem? If so, I don't really think this is the place to ask. It's not clear to me what you're asking.

**Comment by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on 2016-08-18**:
No, I want you to tell ME what to look at and what concepts should I use in ROS in order to start